# I need help in updating multiple records from listview to access in a single click using vbnet

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, ms-access

I have 3 records in ListView1 with 3 fields connected in Table1

Item Code | Description |  Quantity
001 | Apple | 1
002 | Orange | 2
003 | Banana |  3

Then also 3 records in My Database Table2 with 3 fields
Item Code | Description | Qty inventory
001 | Apple | 10
002 | Orange | 20
003 | Banana |  30

My query is how can I update all those 3 records from my listview1 in a single click using VBnet with access database.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for using a `ListView` in the first place? Most people who use one should be using a `DataGridView` instead. A `ListView` doesn't support data-binding so you have to push the data into it and pull it out again manually.  With a `DataGridView`, you use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and then bind that to the grid.  Any changes the user makes through the grid are propagated to the `DataTable` automatically, which is the point of data-binding. You then use the same data adapter to save the changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.

Comment: If you insist on using a `ListView` (which you should not unless you're using multiple views or grouping) then you should still use a data adapter and a `DataTable` in the same way.  The only difference will be that you need to transfer the data from the `DataTable` to the `ListView` and back again manually.  You can easily find examples of doing that.

Comment: Thanks Sir. for your comment. Ill keep it in mind for my next project. Is there anything else we can do for my query?

Comment: You can do exactly what I said in my second comment.

Comment: Are you updated the Qty Inventory to the new value or are you reducing the inventory by the new value?

Comment: Reducing sir......